# How to find the direction angle of a vector when an endpoint isn't the origin

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I know that when a vector has a point on the origin and you are given another point $(x, y)$ that you can find the directional angle by evaluating for θ using the equation $θ = arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. My question is, how would you solve for the direction angle of a vector if you were provided with an endpoint, not the origin and a second point on the vector?

The reason I need to find this is because I don't see how else one would be able to find the component form of such a vector

Comment: The direction with respect that what frame? The one which has the vector's endpoint as origin or the usual one?

Comment: @Joanpemo The direction angle as relates to the origin, although the vector's endpoint does not lie on the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ are given, then the direction is given by
$$θ = \arctan(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})$$

Comment: Could you explain why it is the arctan of the slope? I don't quite understand how you got there.

Comment: For exactly the same reason that in the case $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ then $θ = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. By definition, the directional angle equals the arctangent of the slope.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: It's even "more equal" than that. A vector has no predetermined start or end point, only a direction and distance. The vector from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ is the _same vector_ as the vector from the origin to $(x,y)$ when $x = x_2-x_1$ and $y = y_2-y_1$. So this answer still comes down to $\arctan(y/x)$, after finding the correct values for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the vector's endpoint is $\;P_0:=(x_0,y_0)\;$ and the vector is $\;A:=(a,b)\;$ , then the direction vector is

$$\vec u=P_0-A=\left(a-x_0,\,b-y_0\right)$$

or if you want the angle $\;\alpha\;$ to a line parallel to the $\;x-$axis, then

$$\alpha=\arctan\frac{b-y_0}{a-x_0}$$

assuming $\;a\neq x_0\;$ .

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I'll try it out!

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is trying to say. It seems to say we get a vector $\vec u$ by subtracting another vector from a point, but that does not make sense.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you. It says that the direction vector from point $\;A\;$ to point $\;B\;$ is precisely the (direction) vector $\;\vec{B-A}\;$ . Hopefully I didn't miss anything important.

Comment: I think my confusion was due to the wording "and the vector is $A := (a,b)$. This led me to think $A$ was a vector. But if it is only one endpoint of a vector, that's OK. Subtraction of the two points should produce the vector. (You might still want to be clear which point the vector is "to" and which is subtracted from which, and make sure you do it consistently; $P_0-A$ seems mismatched with $a-x_0$, for example.)

Comment: @DavidK Thank you very much, you're right. I shall edit this.